# Не обновляется Postgresql до 10 версии

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian

При попытке установки чего-либо выходит ошибка о том, что нужно обновить PostgreSql.
Текст:
Устаревшая версия 9.6 PostgreSQL версии 9.6 устарел, но пакет сервера или клиента все ещё установлен. Пожалуйста, установите последние пакеты (postgresql-10 и postgresql-client-10), и обновите ваши существующие кластеры с помощью pg_upgradecluster (см. man-страницу).
При попытке обновления - не обновляется. 
Использовала рекомендации отсюда: https://blackdiver.net/it/linux/4310.
apt-get install -f  не помогает. 
Ошибка:
Работа dpkg прервана, вы должны вручную запустить «sudo dpkg --configure -a» для устранения проблемы.
sudo dpkg --configure -a - снова сообщение о том, что нужно обновить до 10 версии.
Установка 10 версии не получается при помощи apt-get install postgresql-10.
Ошибка: E: Работа dpkg прервана, вы должны вручную запустить «sudo dpkg --configure -a» для устранения проблемы.

Comment: Для начала все же выполните sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: простите! все получилось, инструкция работает. Просто изначально не догадалась, как жать ОК

Comment: добавляйте энтеры в текст и вывод консоли в блоки кода..